# How to check if a specific CSS class is present after opening the dropdown

Tags: javascript, css, contains

I know how to use the "classList.contains" to check if a specific class is contains in an element but the problem is this method only works after loading the DOM only not after that, means In my dropdown menu when the dropdown is opened a "show" class is present to it and I want to implement an animation for this when "show" class is exist on "cc-container" element.

But the "classList.contains" is not working/checking for class "show" on "cc-container" element after clicking the dropdown menu with if else statement.

Please check my JS Snippet.

```js
/*---- NOT WORKING ------*//*

   if(document.querySelector(".cc-container").classList.contains("show")){
   alert("YES");
}else{
   alert("NO");
}

*/

const countryData = [
   { name: "Afganistan", code: "93", flag: "afg" },
   { name: "Albania", code: "355", flag: "alb" },
   { name: "Algeria", code: "213", flag: "dza" },
   { name: "American Samoa", code: "1-684", flag: "asm" },
   { name: "Andorra", code: "376", flag: "and" },
   { name: "Angola", code: "244", flag: "ago" },
   { name: "Anguilla", code: "1-264", flag: "aia" },
   { name: "Antarctica", code: "672", flag: "ata" },
   { name: "Antigua and Barbuda", code: "1-268", flag: "atg" },
   { name: "Argentina", code: "54", flag: "arg" },
   { name: "Armenia", code: "374", flag: "arm" },
   { name: "Aruba", code: "297", flag: "abw" },
   { name: "Australia", code: "61", flag: "aus" },
   { name: "Austria", code: "43", flag: "aut" },
   { name: "Azerbaijan", code: "994", flag: "aze" },
   { name: "Bahamas", code: "1-242", flag: "bhs" },
   { name: "Bahrain", code: "973", flag: "bhr" },
   { name: "Bangladesh", code: "880", flag: "bgd" },
   { name: "Barbados", code: "1-246", flag: "brb" },
   { name: "Belarus", code: "375", flag: "blr" },
   { name: "Belgium", code: "32", flag: "bel" },
   { name: "Belize", code: "501", flag: "blz" },
   { name: "Benin", code: "229", flag: "ben" },
   { name: "Bermuda", code: "1-441", flag: "bmu" },
   { name: "Bhutan", code: "975", flag: "btn" },
   { name: "Bolivia", code: "591", flag: "bol" },
   { name: "Bosnia and Herzegovina", code: "387", flag: "bih" },
   { name: "Botswana", code: "267", flag: "bwa" },
   { name: "Brazil", code: "55", flag: "bra" },
   { name: "British Indian Ocean Territory", code: "246", flag: "iot" },
   { name: "British Virgin Islands", code: "1-284", flag: "vgb" },
   { name: "Brunei", code: "673", flag: "brn" },
   { name: "Bulgaria", code: "359", flag: "bgr" },
   { name: "Burkina Faso", code: "226", flag: "bfa" },
   { name: "Burundi", code: "257", flag: "bdi" },
   { name: "Cambodia", code: "855", flag: "khm" },
];

function registerForm(formRoot) {
  const ccButton = formRoot.querySelector(".cc-telcode");
  const ccContainer = formRoot.querySelector(".cc-container");
  const ccSearchInput = formRoot.querySelector(".cc-search-box");
  const ccList = formRoot.querySelector(".cc-data-list");
  let selectedCountry = ""; 

  ccButton.addEventListener("click", handleButton);
  ccSearchInput.addEventListener("input", handleInput);
  ccList.addEventListener("click", handleListClick);
  document.addEventListener("click", handleDocumentClick);

  function handleDocumentClick(e) {
    const { parentElement } = e.target;
    document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      if (!formRoot.contains(event.target)) {
        ccContainer.classList.remove("show-cc-list");
      }
    });
  }

  function handleButton() {
    ccContainer.classList.toggle("show-cc-list");
    ccList.innerHTML = createListHtml(countryData);
  }

  function createListHtml(countryData) {
    return countryData.map((obj) => {
        const { name, code, flag } = obj;
        let isSelected = "";
        if (obj.name == selectedCountry) isSelected = "selected-country";
        return `
          <li class="cc-list-items ${isSelected}" data-name="${name}" data-code="${code}" data-flag="${flag}">
              <div class="flag-icon flag-icon-${flag}"></div>
              <div class="name">${name} (+${code})</div>
          </li>
        `;
      }).join("");
  }

  function handleInput(e) {
    const { value } = e.target;
    if (value) {
      const filtered = filterData(countryData, value);
      if (filtered.length) {
        ccList.innerHTML = createListHtml(filtered);
      } else {
        ccList.innerHTML = createNoDataHtml();
      }
    } else {
      ccList.innerHTML = createListHtml(countryData);
    }
  }

  function handleListClick(e) {
    const item = e.target.closest("li") || e.target;
    if (item.classList.contains("cc-list-items")) {
      const { code, flag } = item.dataset;
      selectedCountry = item.dataset.name;
      ccButton.innerHTML = createButtonHtml(code, flag);
      ccContainer.classList.remove("show-cc-list");
    }
  }

}


function filterData(countryData, value) {
  return countryData.filter((obj) => {
    return (
      obj.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(value.toLowerCase()) ||
      obj.code.toLowerCase().startsWith(value.toLowerCase())
    );
  });
}

function createButtonHtml(code, flag) {
  return `
    <div class="flag-icon flag-icon-${flag}"></div>
    <option class="cc-code" value="+${code}">+${code}</option>
  `;
}

function createNoDataHtml() {
  return '<li class="no-data-found">Sorry, No Data Found</li>';
}

const contactDiv = document.querySelector(".contact-frm-cc");

registerForm(contactDiv);
```

```css
.cc-telcode {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.cc-telcode div.cc-code,
.cc-list-items div.name {
  margin-left: 0.25em;
}
.cc-container {
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
}
.show-cc-list {
  display: block;
  z-index: +999;
}
.cc-data-list {
  max-height: 100px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1em 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px soldi darkgray;
}
.cc-list-items {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.25em;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
.cc-list-items:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}

.selected-country {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(73, 118, 241);
}

.contact-frm-cc,
.consult-frm-cc {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://amitdutta.co.in/flag/css/flag-icon.css">
<div class="contact-frm-cc">
  <button class="cc-telcode">Tel code</button>
  <section class="cc-container">
    <input type="text" class="cc-search-box" placeholder="Search for country" />
    <ul class="cc-data-list">
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to add an [Event Listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to "listen" when the drop down is opened. Then you can get the class addition/removal.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple css animation using `keyframes`. Note the `forwards`. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode#syntax).

See example below.

Other solutions if you need to do more than a simple animation:

1. use your `handleListClick` method to inject css or manipulate your element.
2. You can also use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) which is very weird in that use case (to be honest)

```js
const countryData = [
   { name: "Afganistan", code: "93", flag: "afg" },
   { name: "Albania", code: "355", flag: "alb" },
   { name: "Algeria", code: "213", flag: "dza" },
   { name: "American Samoa", code: "1-684", flag: "asm" },
   { name: "Andorra", code: "376", flag: "and" },
   { name: "Angola", code: "244", flag: "ago" },
   { name: "Anguilla", code: "1-264", flag: "aia" },
   { name: "Antarctica", code: "672", flag: "ata" },
   { name: "Antigua and Barbuda", code: "1-268", flag: "atg" },
   { name: "Argentina", code: "54", flag: "arg" },
   { name: "Armenia", code: "374", flag: "arm" },
   { name: "Aruba", code: "297", flag: "abw" },
   { name: "Australia", code: "61", flag: "aus" },
   { name: "Austria", code: "43", flag: "aut" },
   { name: "Azerbaijan", code: "994", flag: "aze" },
   { name: "Bahamas", code: "1-242", flag: "bhs" },
   { name: "Bahrain", code: "973", flag: "bhr" },
   { name: "Bangladesh", code: "880", flag: "bgd" },
   { name: "Barbados", code: "1-246", flag: "brb" },
   { name: "Belarus", code: "375", flag: "blr" },
   { name: "Belgium", code: "32", flag: "bel" },
   { name: "Belize", code: "501", flag: "blz" },
   { name: "Benin", code: "229", flag: "ben" },
   { name: "Bermuda", code: "1-441", flag: "bmu" },
   { name: "Bhutan", code: "975", flag: "btn" },
   { name: "Bolivia", code: "591", flag: "bol" },
   { name: "Bosnia and Herzegovina", code: "387", flag: "bih" },
   { name: "Botswana", code: "267", flag: "bwa" },
   { name: "Brazil", code: "55", flag: "bra" },
   { name: "British Indian Ocean Territory", code: "246", flag: "iot" },
   { name: "British Virgin Islands", code: "1-284", flag: "vgb" },
   { name: "Brunei", code: "673", flag: "brn" },
   { name: "Bulgaria", code: "359", flag: "bgr" },
   { name: "Burkina Faso", code: "226", flag: "bfa" },
   { name: "Burundi", code: "257", flag: "bdi" },
   { name: "Cambodia", code: "855", flag: "khm" },
];

function registerForm(formRoot) {
  const ccButton = formRoot.querySelector(".cc-telcode");
  const ccContainer = formRoot.querySelector(".cc-container");
  const ccSearchInput = formRoot.querySelector(".cc-search-box");
  const ccList = formRoot.querySelector(".cc-data-list");
  let selectedCountry = ""; 

  ccButton.addEventListener("click", handleButton);
  ccSearchInput.addEventListener("input", handleInput);
  ccList.addEventListener("click", handleListClick);
  document.addEventListener("click", handleDocumentClick);

  function handleDocumentClick(e) {
    const { parentElement } = e.target;
    document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      if (!formRoot.contains(event.target)) {
        ccContainer.classList.remove("show-cc-list");
      }
    });
  }

  function handleButton() {
    ccContainer.classList.toggle("show-cc-list");
    ccList.innerHTML = createListHtml(countryData);
  }

  function createListHtml(countryData) {
    return countryData.map((obj) => {
        const { name, code, flag } = obj;
        let isSelected = "";
        if (obj.name == selectedCountry) isSelected = "selected-country";
        return `
          <li class="cc-list-items ${isSelected}" data-name="${name}" data-code="${code}" data-flag="${flag}">
              <div class="flag-icon flag-icon-${flag}"></div>
              <div class="name">${name} (+${code})</div>
          </li>
        `;
      }).join("");
  }

  function handleInput(e) {
    const { value } = e.target;
    if (value) {
      const filtered = filterData(countryData, value);
      if (filtered.length) {
        ccList.innerHTML = createListHtml(filtered);
      } else {
        ccList.innerHTML = createNoDataHtml();
      }
    } else {
      ccList.innerHTML = createListHtml(countryData);
    }
  }

  function handleListClick(e) {
    const item = e.target.closest("li") || e.target;
    if (item.classList.contains("cc-list-items")) {
      const { code, flag } = item.dataset;
      selectedCountry = item.dataset.name;
      ccButton.innerHTML = createButtonHtml(code, flag);
      ccContainer.classList.remove("show-cc-list");
    }
  }

}


function filterData(countryData, value) {
  return countryData.filter((obj) => {
    return (
      obj.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(value.toLowerCase()) ||
      obj.code.toLowerCase().startsWith(value.toLowerCase())
    );
  });
}

function createButtonHtml(code, flag) {
  return `
    <div class="flag-icon flag-icon-${flag}"></div>
    <option class="cc-code" value="+${code}">+${code}</option>
  `;
}

function createNoDataHtml() {
  return '<li class="no-data-found">Sorry, No Data Found</li>';
}

const contactDiv = document.querySelector(".contact-frm-cc");

registerForm(contactDiv);
```

```css
.cc-telcode {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.cc-telcode div.cc-code,
.cc-list-items div.name {
  margin-left: 0.25em;
}
.cc-container {
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
}
.show-cc-list {
  display: block;
  z-index: +999;
}
.cc-data-list {
  max-height: 100px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1em 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px soldi darkgray;
}
.cc-list-items {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.25em;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
.cc-list-items:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}

.selected-country {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(73, 118, 241);
}

.contact-frm-cc,
.consult-frm-cc {
  width: 100px;
}

/* ADDED */
@keyframes deploy {
  from {
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

/* Always make your code compliant with accessibility preferences */
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .show-cc-list .cc-data-list {
    animation: deploy .3s ease-out forwards;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://amitdutta.co.in/flag/css/flag-icon.css">
<div class="contact-frm-cc">
  <button class="cc-telcode">Tel code</button>
  <section class="cc-container">
    <input type="text" class="cc-search-box" placeholder="Search for country" />
    <ul class="cc-data-list">
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Sir how to apply reverse animation, means when dropdown menu is closed?

Comment: As I told you: for more in-depth usage, use javascript, create eventListeners on click and check for the current display state of your element.